# How can I link from Heroku to github pages via iframe?

Tags: iframe, heroku, github, github-pages, mixed-content

My heroku app depends on github pages via iframes, which doesn't work as the browser tells me its Mixed content. So

```
<iframe src="//larsvers.github.io/tree-of-charts"></iframe>
```

produces an empty iframe with the chrome console error

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://gradients10.herokuapp.com/project/tree-of-charts' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://larsvers.github.io/tree-of-charts/'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

I assume github's https is not fully fledged so heroku won't point to it. I tried using `target="_parent"` (as someone suggested on [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Why-would-links-on-my-Heroku-app-not-work-from-an-error-maintenance-page-hosted-on-Amazon-S3)) without much luck.

Would anyone know a fix to this? Or an alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to be more specific and use

```
<iframe src="//larsvers.github.io/tree-of-charts/"></iframe>
```

denoting the path as a directory with a **trailing backslash**. It seems https (and url naming etiquette) requires this level of specificity...